# "Hardest part of" vs. "hardest part about"

Tags: differences, prepositions, phrase-usage

Is there a major difference between the two? I'm sure they're both equally acceptable. For instance:

> "The hardest part of travelling is..."

or

> "The hardest part about travelling is..."

Comment: They are both idiomatic and in regular use. Though they may be used differently according to circumstance, including, for example, in speech versus written form.

Comment: The second seems distinctly odd to me. You speak of 'a part of' something, not 'a part about' it. Maybe, if people do indeed use that phrase, it's by confusion with "The hardest thing about travelling".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While they are both used and would presumably both be understood, the second construction has a grammatical dissonance to it.

While it makes sense to speak of "a part of," you would not speak of "a part about." An alternative phrase, "the hardest thing about" makes more sense.

For that reason, I would suggest avoiding "hardest part about" in favor of "hardest part of." If you need to use "about" for lyrical or poetic reasons, use "thing" instead of "part."

A quick [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hardest%20part%20of%2Chardest%20part%20about%2Chardest%20thing%20about&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chardest%20part%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardest%20part%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardest%20thing%20about%3B%2Cc0) search (for whatever it's worth) shows "part of" is by far the more common phrase, with "part about" and even "thing about" negligible by comparison.

*edit: Kate Bunting makes this point in the comments to the question.*